# Error parsing parquet file and importing data to sql table using pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, sql-server, pandas, pyodbc

Seeing below error while trying to read parquet file and import the data to Microsoft SQL Server table, couldn't figure out where the problem is, any suggestions would be helpful.

code snippet:

```
from pandas import read_parquet
import numpy as np
df = read_parquet('<file-path>', engine='fastparquet')
df = df.fillna(value=np.nan)
cols = "],[".join([str(i) for i in df.columns.tolist()])
           for index, row in df.iterrows():
                sql = "INSERT INTO " + obj.table + "([" + cols + "]) VALUES (" + "?," * (len(row) - 1) + "?)"
                try:
                    cur.execute(sql, tuple(row))
                except:
                    print(sql, tuple(row))
                    tb.print_exc()
                    break
                conn.commit()
```

Error (printed record that failed insert):

```
<For debugging>
INSERT INTO table(col1, col2 col3 ...) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) (294958881.0, 0.0, 71142106.0, 5.0, 4.0, 4.0, 0.0, 4804102.0, 1.0, 1.0, Timestamp('2020-01-30 12:00:01.590000'), Timestamp('2020-01-30 12:05:12.480000'), nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, Timestamp('2020-01-30 12:05:00'), Timestamp('2020-01-30 12:05:12.420000'), Timestamp('2020-01-30 12:05:12.420000'), nan, nan, nan, 130864939.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 253199575.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, nan, 0.0, 0.0, nan, nan, nan, nan, 1.0, 1.0, '63D861B100000001', Timestamp('2023-01-31 00:32:49.265000'), Timestamp('2023-01-31 00:32:49'))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\temp\file.py", line 293, in method01
    cur.execute(sql, tuple(row))
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect. 
Parameter 16 (""): The supplied value is not a valid instance of data type float. Check the source data for invalid values. 
An example of an invalid value is data of numeric type with scale greater than precision. (8023) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

I don't have any float values here that the error is reporting, not sure if I'm missing something. All my target columns are nullable.

Comment: Aside... `nan` is not a float and should probably get converted to `None`.

Comment: You are using Pandas to read the parquet file. Is there some reason you are not using Panda's [`to_sql`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) to insert the data in SQL Server?

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try with both suggestions and get back to you.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I have tried two different things, 
1. Replacing the nan to an empty string using `df.fillna(value='')`, this resolved the loading errors with an execution time of `20+ minutes` to load/insert 2M records.
2. using sqlalchemy create engine + `df.to_sql`, no errors reported but the loading time is `2+ hours` for same data set. I have tried the `fast_executemany=True` with sqlalchmey connection but the performance is same.

Answer (score 0):

I have following two methods working with some exceptions,

**Method 1**: (Based on suggestion in one of the comments)

> Using SqlAlchemy, pyodbc

```
import sqlalchemy as sa, pyodbc
con = sa.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://'
                        +self.server+'/'
                        +self.database+
                        '?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0'
                        , fast_executemany=True
                        , echo=False)

from pandas import read_parquet
df = read_parquet('<file-path>', engine='fastparquet')
df.to_sql(name=self.table, con=con, if_exists='append', chunksize=1000, index=False)
con.dispose()
```

Observations using method 1:

- Slow loading.
- No issues with NaN values from pandas df (My original problem).
- 5x slower than method 2, when tested with 100MB compressed parquet file.

**Method 2**: (If you are not worried of NaNs in the dataframe and need faster load time)

> using pyodbc

```
import pyodbc
con = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
                      "SERVER=" + self.server + ";"
                      "DATABASE=" + self.database + ";"
                      "Trusted_Connection=yes;")
cur = con.cursor()
from pandas import read_parquet
df = read_parquet('<file-path>', engine='fastparquet')
df.fillna(value='', inplace=True)
for index, row in df.iterrows():
     sql = "INSERT INTO " + self.table + "([" + cols + "]) VALUES (" + "?," * (len(row) - 1) + "?)"
     cur.execute(sql, tuple(row))
     con.commit()
con.close()
```

Observations using method 2:

- Fast loading.
- No issues with NaN values, as we are marking them to empty string.
- 5x faster than method 1, when tested with 100MB compressed parquet file.

Comment: The results you report are most unusual. I have never seen a situation where sending an individual INSERT statement for each row via `.execute()` is faster than a method that can use `.executemany()` like `.to_sql()` can.

Comment: I have tested this on multiple files, but the outcome is observed same. The only difference I have noticed with method 1 vs 2 is, with 1 there is single commit which means if my df has 2M rows, I'm seeing the commit happens only after all 2M  inserts whereas with 2 it is for each row as in loop. Not sure if that makes any difference with speed here.